# Difference between leaked android 5.0 and Official Samsung

Tags: android-versions, samsung-galaxy-note-3

Is there any difference between leaked version of android 5.0 for Samsung galaxy notes and the Official release from febuary

Answer (score 0):

This case is about **`Download Server`** and also For **`Region`** and add Language & another reasons.

About Download server, it can maybe not safe and its better to download from `Official`, `valid` and `Safe` server.and also it can a `Custom Rom`.

like : [Sam mobile](http://www.sammobile.com)

its safe and valid.

Comment: I am right now on leaked version and I consider whether to install official from Sammobile or not I mean if in the official release are something more or something important was fixed by devs.

Comment: Of course, but its better to tell us what leaked version and from where !

Comment: I have found this one on xda and was  excited so I have installed. The  version is N9005XXEGBNL8

Comment: I think, this is official and used by developers or after phone devastation.but, i can't make a decision right now, this is safe or work good.but, there's not special differents between one file (tar.md5) with this 5 file.

Comment: Ok so at the moment I will stay with this one I will wait for 5.1 update if it will come some day. Thanks for help.

Comment: your welcome, also use this for find : [Sam Mobile-Firmwares](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/database/SM-N9005/)